# Is there any way to code canvas in react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, canvas

I am going to write a canvas picture with dynamic data on react-native app, but I find it that there is not any canvas component on react-native. Is there any better choice ?

Comment: Did you try react-native-canvas? https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas

Comment: solved by using react native webview 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[react-native-webviewe](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)

the webview solved my problem! Feel free to code canvas or other html ~